# How to unify columns between multiple data frames which has different columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, multiple-columns, padding

I have data frames as below:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=c(1:5), b=c(6:10), c=c(11:15))
df2 <- data.frame(a=c(1:5), c=c(11:15))
```

Though `df2` is missing column `b`, I would like to unite columns in both data frames (padding non-exist columns by `NA`).

```
> df2
  a  b  c
1 1 NA 11
2 2 NA 12
3 3 NA 13
4 4 NA 14
5 5 NA 15
```

There are multiple data frames in actual environment.
Most of them have complete columns but some data frames miss some columns.

I think there are ways to take full columns' name by `names()` from one specific data frame and apply it to all data frames. I prefer to use `dplyr` in `R`.

I appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bind_rows using an id, then filter on the id you want, then deselect id

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% bind_rows( df2, .id = "id" ) %>%
  filter( id == 2 ) %>%
  select( -id )

  a  b  c
1 1 NA 11
2 2 NA 12
3 3 NA 13
4 4 NA 14
5 5 NA 15
```

Comment: Thank you for your idea. Though I prefer not to add and delete rows from other data frames, it is fast way and worked out easily.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution

```
# Create skeleton data.frame based on df1
# and fill with NAs
df.new <- df1;
df.new[] <- NA;

# Fill with entries from df2
df.new[colnames(df2)] <- df2;
#  a  b  c
#1 1 NA 11
#2 2 NA 12
#3 3 NA 13
#4 4 NA 14
#5 5 NA 15
```

Answer (score 0):

An option in `base-R` can be achieved using `merge` on data frames and then `intersect` over column names as:

```
df_new <- merge(df1, df2)
df_new[,!(names(df_new) %in% intersect(names(df1), names(df2)))] <- NA
df_new
#   a  c  b
# 1 1 11 NA
# 2 2 12 NA
# 3 3 13 NA
# 4 4 14 NA
# 5 5 15 NA
```

A `dplyr` based solution can be as:

```
library(dplyr)

merge(df1, df2) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-one_of(intersect(names(df1), names(df2)))),
                                      funs(replace(.,!is.na(.),NA)))

#   a  c  b
# 1 1 11 NA
# 2 2 12 NA
# 3 3 13 NA
# 4 4 14 NA
# 5 5 15 NA
```